# 419 Sorry, your session has expired. Please refresh and try again

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

https://www.demoniakmachine.com/notes/login

Before it was :

```
Route::get('auth/login', ["as" => "login_form", "uses" =>
        function()
        {
            return view("auth/login");
        }]
);

Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');


Route::post('post_images', function () {
    require_once("../app_tinymce_file_acceptor.php");
});


Route::get('auth/register', ["as" => "register", "uses" =>
    function() {
        return view('auth\register');
    }]);
Route::post('auth/register', ['as' => 'register_submit', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister']);

Route::get('radio', ['middleware' => "auth", "uses" => function () {
    return view('radio.index');
}]);
```

Then fill the form and login.

I got an error that I ve never seen before:

```
https://www.demoniakmachine.com/notes/auth/login
 419

Sorry, your session has expired. Please refresh and try again.
```

I try this:
- update to 5.7.9
- check sessions and purge the session directory.
- generate new appkey, running artisan and composer numerous times.

And I don't see the solution.

I misunderstand why {{asset("auth/login")}} leads to "login" (whitout "auth") and the form post leads to "auth/login".

As I read, Laravel perhaps wants Users to use the builtin login/register. How to use this feature from an ?

HTML source of login page:

Successs... demoniakmachine.com.mysql via TCP/IP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="RbGZ2IZJJWZkWcTT7kUS1waVtvCWfctQp3fScjT8">

    <title>Laravel</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="https://www.demoniakmachine.com/notes/js/app.js" defer></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="https://www.demoniakmachine.com/notes/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light navbar-laravel">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://www.demoniakmachine.com/notes">
                    Laravel
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.demoniakmachine.com/notes/auth/login">Login</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                                                    <a class="nav-link" href="https://www.demoniakmachine.com/notes/auth/register">Register</a>
                                                            </li>
                                            </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <main class="py-4">
            <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Login</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="https://www.demoniakmachine.com/notes/auth/login">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="RbGZ2IZJJWZkWcTT7kUS1waVtvCWfctQp3fScjT8">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-md-right">E-Mail Address</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="" required autofocus>

                                                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                                                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" >

                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                                        Remember Me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Login
                                </button>

                                <a class="btn btn-link" href="https://www.demoniakmachine.com/notes/password/reset">
                                    Forgot Your Password?
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can update your `login.blade.php` contents as well ?

Comment: You hard-coded the token or this is generated html ?

Answer (score 1):

Include the `csrf_token` in your form as,

```
<form action="...">
    @csrf
```

Comment: I've check that, too.

Answer (score 0):

Include the `csrf_field()` in your form.

```
<form method="POST" action="https://www.demoniakmachine.com/notes/auth/login">
{{ csrf_field() }}
```